# Clojure for loop not returning updated values of atom

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function that counts the number of vowels and consonants in a given string. The return value is a map with two keys, `vowels` and `consonants`. The values for each respective key are simply the counts.

The function that I have been able to develop so far is

```
(defn count-vowels-consenants [s]
  (let [m (atom {"vowels" 0 "consenants" 0})
        v #{"a" "e" "i" "o" "u"}]
    (for [xs s]
      (if
          (contains? v (str xs))
            (swap! m update-in ["vowels"] inc)
            (swap! m update-in ["consenants"] inc)
       ))
    @m))
```

however `(count-vowels-consenants "sldkfjlskjwe")` returns `{"vowels":0 "consenants": 0}`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: changed my input from `str` to `s` as `str` is a function in Clojure.

Comment: Is updating an atom a requirement?

Comment: @jmargolisvt no, there's no specific requirement for an atom. It seemed to me to be the natural way to mutate state with Clojure, but i'm completely open to alternatives.

Comment: Though you've already received answers to your question, I wanted to highlight the fundamental misunderstanding here that you likely realize by now -- there is no "for loop" in clojure.  `for` is a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) construct, used for creating a list, and as such, it does not "loop" (as you've seen, `loop` is appropriately named). It can be confusing coming from imperative languages that feature the word `for` in a looping context, but this is not what it means in clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `for` is lazy so you're not going to actually do anything until you try to realize it. I added a `first` onto the `for` loop which realized the list and resulted in an error which you made by overwriting the `str` function with the `str` string. Ideally, you would just do this without the atom rigmarole.

```
(defn count-vowels-consonants [s]
  (let [v #{\a \e \i \o \u}
        vowels (filter v s)
        consonants (remove v s)]
    {:consonants (count consonants)
     :vowels (count vowels)}))
```

if the atom is what you want, then use `doseq` instead of `for` and it will update the atom for everything in the string. also make sure you don't overwrite the `str` function by using it in your function binding.

Comment: FYI, a `group-by` is probably better since it'll only do one iteration over the string/seq.

Comment: @Brandon H ahhhh, good catch with `str`, that's really sloppy on my part.

Comment: This is definitely more elegant than my solution. Thanks for pointing me to `doseq`.

Answer (score 2):

if this side effecting scheme is inevitable (for sume educational reason, i suppose) just replace `for` with [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) which is a side effecting eager equivalent of `for`
(by the way: there is a mistake in your initial code: you use `str` as an input param name, and then try to use it as a function. So you are shadowing the def from the clojure.core, just try to avoid using params named like the core functions):

```
(defn count-vowels-consenants [input]
  (let [m (atom {"vowels" 0 "consenants" 0})
        v #{"a" "e" "i" "o" "u"}]
    (doseq [s input]
      (if (contains? v (str s))
        (swap! m update-in ["vowels"] inc)
        (swap! m update-in ["consenants"] inc)))
    @m))
#'user/count-vowels-consenants

user> (count-vowels-consenants "asdfg")
;; {"vowels" 1, "consenants" 4}
```

otherwise you could do something like this:

```
user> (reduce #(update %1
                       (if (#{\a \e \i \o \u} %2) 
                         "vowels" "consonants")
                       (fnil inc 0))
              {} "qwertyui")
;;{"consonants" 5, "vowels" 3}
```

or

```
user> (frequencies (map #(if (#{\a \e \i \o \u} %)
                           "vowels" "consonants")
                        "qwertyui"))
;;{"consonants" 5, "vowels" 3}
```

or this (if you're good with having `true/false` instead of "vowels/consonants"):

```
user> (frequencies (map (comp some? #{\a \e \i \o \u}) "qwertyui"))
;;{false 5, true 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

for is lazy as mentioned by @Brandon H. You can use loop recur if you want. Here I change for with loop-recur.

```
(defn count-vowels-consenants [input]
  (let [m (atom {"vowels" 0 "consenants" 0})
        v #{"a" "e" "i" "o" "u"}]
    (loop [s input]
      (when (> (count s) 0)
      (if
          (contains? v (first (str s) ))
            (swap! m update-in ["vowels"] inc)
            (swap! m update-in ["consenants"] inc)
       ))
       (recur (apply str (rest s))))
    @m))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question, and every extant answer, assumes that every character is a vowel or a consonant: not so. And even in ASCII, there are lower and upper case letters. I'd do it as follows ...

```
(defn count-vowels-consonants [s]
  (let [vowels  #{\a \e \i \o \u
                  \A \E \I \O \U}
        classify (fn [c]
                   (if (Character/isLetter c)
                     (if (vowels c) :vowel :consonant)))]
    (map-v count (dissoc (group-by classify s) nil))))
```

... where `map-v` is a function that `map`'s the values of a map:

```
(defn map-v [f m] (reduce (fn [a [k v]] (assoc a k (f v))) {} m))
```

For example,

```
(count-vowels-consonants "s2a Boo!")
;{:vowel 3, :consonant 2}
```

This traverses the string just once.